# Chevron Usage in Menu Items

Tags: mobile, navigation, menu

In a banking mobile app, all menu items have chevrons but some of them open bottom sheet instead of going to a new page. In the example below, Menu Item 1 can open a bottom sheet where as Menu Item 2 goes to the its own flow.

**Question:**
Do you think it is confusing to use chevrons when the item opens a bottom sheet? Or would it be more confusing if some of the menu items have chevrons and some of them won't?

[image]

Thanks, I am looking forward for any opinions.

Comment: If it's going to open a bottom sheet, use the v chevron. If it's going to open a new page, stick with the > chevron.

Comment: In addition to Luke's suggestion, you can make the bottom sheets as accordions instead of opening so far down below.

Comment: @luke I think `v` will be confused with an accordion

Comment: @Shahriar Which, as Steve points out, is what it should be anyway. Separating the menu item from its content by other menu items is not a great idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the items have different behaviors, then they shouldn't have a similar icon.
What I suggest is a button.
[image]